# Append 'Read More' link after a certain number of characters and hide the rest

Tags: javascript, jquery

In jQuery how can I append a "Read More" link after about 162 char's, hide the rest and once the read more link is clicked, show it, clicked it... hide it.

I've looked at other questions, but the answers are having another div that has the rest of the text in it. I don't want to do that, really.

I am trying to a paragraph of text, thats all.

```
<p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna                                enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip
                        </p>
```

Comment: How do you want to do it then? I mean, you could use a SPAN instead of a DIV, if you want to be semantic.

Comment: Well, I guess wrap the char's after the wanted amount and then hide?

Comment: you could use the overflow property with a div with fixed size (but you'll have to care about cross-browser compatibility). Could you explain why you don't want another div ?

Comment: That's one way. It's hard to tell, since you didn't post any code for your attempt(s). Are you needing to do client-side only (meaning injecting any markup could not be server-side)? What are you dealing with? You could truncate at 161 using Javascript and add the rest to a `rel` attribute for that, and trigger it on click of your (js-inserted) element, which could add/remove your `rel` text. There's really a bunch of different ways, considering what you're up against and what you've tried. :)

Comment: The client knows little html. I was hoping he can just go in the code, which he doesn't mind and add much text as he want, without worrying about how many characters he has to have, etc. and have have the code do the hiding for it

Comment: It's just a paragraph of text. Thats all.

Comment: There are many plugins for showing readmore text.  try http://plugins.learningjquery.com/expander/

Answer (score 6):

Here you go:

http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/9t3Z5/3/

**HTML:**

```
<div id="my_text" class="ellipsis">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ........ </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ellipsis {
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -moz-binding: url('http://seancannon.com/_test/ellipsis.xml#ellipsis');
}

#my_text {
    font-family:arial;
    color:#333;
    font-size:10px;
    width:80%;
}


#read_more {
    border:1px solid #000;
    background-color:#CCC;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

**JQuery:**

```
$('#read_more').click(function(){
    $('#my_text').toggleClass('ellipsis');
});

// Don't show Read More button if fewer than 500 chars
$(function(){
    if($('#my_text').html().length < 500)
    {
        $('#read_more').hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: Could you append the read more div inside of the paragraph div?

Comment: You don't want to put a div inside a paragraph, but you can always use CSS to make it appear as such with positioning, etc.

Comment: Is it possible to disable the read more link untill theres a certain amount of chars?

Comment: @kdevs3 - If you found this answer useful and solves your problem, please click the outlined checkmark next to the question, and/or upvote it as well. :)